# TargetInvocationException sitecollection "no access" quota

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-collection

I am getting this error:

```
+ CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [CheckSiteCollection], TargetInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,CheckSiteCollection
```

when I do this:

```
foreach($webApp in Get-SPWebApplication) {
    DoSomething($webApp.Sites)
}
```

the error occurs at the `DoSomething` function. If I add a `try` `catch` around it, that stops the error message but it doesn't allow the script to go on.

The only time I get this message is when a site collection is set to "No Access" under the quota's page of central admin.

**Question**: how do I either skip sites that are locked with "No Access" or catch the error but allow the script to continue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following URL should help you:
[Check SharePoint 2010 Site Collection Locks with PowerShell](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/289/Check-SharePoint-2010-Site-Collection-Locks-with-PowerShell.aspx)

From the article above:

> - When UI value “No Access”
>       ReadOnly = null 
>    ReadLocked = null
>    WriteLocked = null
>
> When No Access is set, that puts an explicit Deny permission on the
>   site collection, which prevents the values from being read.  Therefore
>   it shows null values.  Who wants to remember all that?  How can we tie
>   all this together and get a value for these easily?
>
> ```
>  Add-pssnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
>
>  $sites = get-spsite -limit all | foreach {
>   write-host "Checking lock for site collection: " $_.RootWeb.Title -foregroundcolor blue
>     if ($_.ReadOnly -eq $false -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $false)
>        { write-host "The site lock value for the site collection"$_.RootWeb.Title "is:  Unlocked" -foregroundcolor Green}
>          if ($_.lockissue -ne $null) {
>          write-host "The additional text was provided for the lock: " $_.LockIssue -foregroundcolor Green}
>     elseif ($_.ReadOnly -eq $false -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $true)
>        { write-host "The site lock value for the site collection"$_.RootWeb.Title "is:  Adding Content Prevented" -foregroundcolor Green}
>    elseif ($_.ReadOnly -eq $true -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $false -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $true)
>       { write-host "The site lock value for the site collection"$_.RootWeb.Title "is:  Read-only" -foregroundcolor Green}
>    elseif ($_.ReadOnly -eq $null -and $_.ReadLocked -eq $null -and $_.WriteLocked -eq $null)
>       { write-host "The site lock value for the site collection"$_.RootWeb.Title "is:  No Access" -foregroundcolor Green}  
>
>  }
> ```

Comment: thanks. that does the trick. I don't know how I didn't get this when I googled for it.